# Different colors of active button with Bootstrap and Angular ngFor

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I have a menu with four buttons that when activated have a defined color but this color is for all four, the same as the rollOver. Is there a way to define a color for each button, both for the active state and the rollover?

[image]

.html

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills subNav">
      <li class="nav-item" *ngFor="let linea of lineas">
        <a class="nav-link rounded-circle p-3 m-2 m-lg-3" routerLink="{{linea.url}}" routerLinkActive="active" >
          <img class="iconProduct" src="{{ linea.image }}">
        </a>
        <p class="small text-center">{{ linea.titulo }}</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

.ts

```
this.lineas = [
      { image: 'assets/images/icon1.svg', url:'url1', titulo: 'title1'},
      { image: 'assets/images/icon2.svg', url:'url2', titulo: 'title2' },
      { image: 'assets/images/icon3.svg', url:'url3', titulo: 'title3'},
      { image: 'assets/images/icon4.svg', url:'url4', titulo: 'title4' }
      ]
```

.scss

```
.subNav .nav-link {
  background-color: #d5d5d5;
}
```

Comment: routerLinkActive="active"  - active is nothing but the css class to be apply when link become active

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to set a background color for the `active` and `hover` states that is different for each button is with the [:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) CSS pseudo-class:

```
.subNav > .nav-item:nth-child(1) > .nav-link:hover,
.subNav > .nav-item:nth-child(1) > .nav-link.active {
  background-color: orange;
}

.subNav > .nav-item:nth-child(2) > .nav-link:hover,
.subNav > .nav-item:nth-child(2) > .nav-link.active {
  background-color: green;
}

.subNav > .nav-item:nth-child(3) > .nav-link:hover,
.subNav > .nav-item:nth-child(3) > .nav-link.active {
  background-color: red;
}

.subNav > .nav-item:nth-child(4) > .nav-link:hover,
.subNav > .nav-item:nth-child(4) > .nav-link.active {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slczmd) for a demo.

---

An alternative technique is to define the active state color in your data structure:

```
this.lineas = [
  { image: 'assets/images/icon1.svg', url:'url1', titulo: 'title1', activeColor: 'lime' },
  { image: 'assets/images/icon2.svg', url:'url2', titulo: 'title2', activeColor: 'green' },
  { image: 'assets/images/icon3.svg', url:'url3', titulo: 'title3', activeColor: 'red' },
  { image: 'assets/images/icon4.svg', url:'url4', titulo: 'title4', activeColor: 'blue'}
];
```

and to apply it to the background style of the link when the `active` class is set:

```
<a #link [style.background-color]="isActive(link) ? linea.activeColor : null" ...>
```

```
isActive(link): boolean {
  return link.classList.contains("active");
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-anv8bv) for a demo. You will notice that I set default color for the `hover` state in that case:

```
.subNav > .nav-item > .nav-link:hover {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
}
```

You may need to process the mouse `enter` and `leave` events if you want to apply the custom background colors defined in the data when the mouse is over the link.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, the first thing worked for me very well, I'm going to review the pseudo classes very well, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

`routerLinkActive` is assigned a class that is supposed to be applied to the `active` `li`. `active` is the class in this case.

Try adding `active` as well to the scss:

```
.active .subNav .nav-link {
  background-color: #d5d5d5;
}
```